# I am trying to use the list I made in my getData function in my normalise function

Tags: python

```
import string

def getData(filename):
  with open(filename,'r') as f:
    lines=[line.rstrip() for line in f]
    lines=[x.lower() for x in lines]
    return lines
filename="bibleSentences.txt"
getData(filename)

def normalize():
    lowercase_lines=[x.lower() for x in lines]
    return lowercase_lines
    normalize(filename)
normalize()
```

I am trying to use the list I made in my `getData` function in my `normalize` function but I am getting an `error` saying that `"lines is not defined"` in the `normalize` function.

I am wondering how to call the function the right way so that I can avoid the error.

Comment: The alignment got messed up when posting

Comment: Return to your tutorials on functions and variable scope.  There is no `lines` variable defined in `normalize`: it's not in the main program, and you failed to pass it as an argument (proper coding practice).  The `lines` variable in `getData` is a local variable.  Again, follow the examples of how to pass values into and out of functions.  Your code is a good practice exercise.

Comment: You're confusing names of local variables with global variables. Also misunderstanding that the statement `return lines` doesn't somehow create a global variable named `lines`, it only returns a value back to the caller; but then doing `getData(filename)` instead of assigning the return value `result = getData(filename)` just throws away that return value from `getData()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you meant:

```
filename="bibleSentences.txt"

def normalize(filename):
    lowercase_lines=[x.lower() for x in getData(filename)]
    return lowercase_lines

normalize(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

What went wrong

When python returned the line variable to you, you didn’t assign it to anything, and therefore just lost it. A better way of doing it would be below.

Improved Code

```
filename="bibleSentences.txt"
lines = getData(filename)

def normalize():
    lowercase_lines=[x.lower() for x in lines]
    return lowercase_lines
lowercase_lines = normalize(lines)
```

Comment: Could somebody format it for me? I am on IOS and struggling to do it with some of the custom chars he keyboard uses. Thanks!